# How to downgrade packages on Ubuntu?

Tags: downgrade

Update Manager keeps packages at the latest version, but occasionally a new package version may not work as expected or properly. **How to downgrade an installed package and lock it** at a specific version to prevent it from being updated? How can I do this **using GUI** or **using a Terminal**?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### In GUI - using Synaptic

The Ubuntu Software Center’s simplified interface doesn’t offer the option to downgrade packages. Synaptic, a more advanced graphical package manager interface that Ubuntu used to include, offers this option. To downgrade a package graphically, first install the [Synaptic](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/synaptic) application:

[image: Ubuntu Software Center]

After you done this, open the Synaptic Package Manager from the Dash:

[image: synaptis]

Search for the package you want to install an older version of in Synaptic, select it, and use the **Package** > **Force Version** option:

[image: Force version]

Select the version you want to install and click Force Version. Synaptic will only show you versions available in your repositories:

[image: Select version]

Click the **Apply** button to apply your changes and install the older version of the package, assuming everything works properly.

[image: Apply]

After you downgrade the package, select it and use the **Package** > **Lock Version** option. If you don’t do this, Ubuntu will try to upgrade the installed package the next time you update your installed packages:

[image: Lock version]

### In Terminal – using `apt-get`

You can install a specific version of a package with `apt-get` in the [Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal). First, determine the available versions you can install with the following command (use for *packagename* the name of the program that you want to downgrade):

```
apt-cache showpkg [packagename]
```

Next, run the apt-get install command and specify the package version you want to install (use for *version* the version number previously determined of the program that you want to downgrade):

```
sudo apt-get install [packagename]=[version]
```

After it’s installed, run the following command to hold your installed version, preventing the package manager from automatically updating it in the future:

```
sudo echo "[packagename] hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

**Source**: http://www.howtogeek.com/117929/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu/

Comment: if you based your answer on this site http://www.howtogeek.com/117929/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu/ please provide source link. I don't think howtogeek will mind but they sure need the proper source link so they can get the credit.

Comment: When I tried to do this I got into all kinds of problems with unmet dependencies. I found it better to use aptitude as this resolved all the dependencies e.g. sudo aptitude install smbclient=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2 . See http://askubuntu.com/questions/770789/how-to-downgrade-smbclient

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility:

Lets find the archived package on http://packages.ubuntu.com/:

For example downgrading php5 :

## Search:

[image]

## Found an exact hit lets look at the package page for php5 :

[image]

## We can see the different versions of Ubuntu releases here we are at trusty:

[image]

## Lets switch to version that ran php (5.3) ... 12.04 (precise) for example:

[image]

## download the tar.gz

[image]

And then extract the tar file and install it:

```
cd /path/to/download
tar -xzvf name_of_package
cd name_of_extracted_folder
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Possible issues that one could run into when running `./configure`:

- Missing dependencies ( had to install `libxm2-dev`):
  [image]

Issues running `make`:

- errors while compiling could include flags not being set properly, or issues with the code itself.
- A bunch of garbage when compiling, and then some issue in the code?
- In my case i had to find the up to date source files/tarball for php ( http://php.net/downloads.php )
- and retry extraction and make