# How can I add a PPA from a previous release?

Tags: ppa, vim

I've been trying to get [vim with the breakindent patch applied](https://launchpad.net/~eudoxos/+archive/vim-breakindent), but it's only available through Quantal, and I'm running Raring. Is there a way to force-install a PPA from a previous release? I tried manually downloading all the packages and running `sudo dpkg -i` but I get lots of errors about dependencies, some of which don't look like they can be resolved. Am I stuck with having to compile vim myself?

Comment: How did you add the PPA, with `add-apt-repository`?  Or have you not added it yet?

Comment: Adding the PPA works, but since its Raring area is empty, apt-get returns `W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/eudoxos/vim-breakindent/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/eudoxos/vim-breakindent/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.` Furthermore, adding an empty repo like that breaks apt-get upgrade, so I have to go in and manually remove the PPA entries from my sources list.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should choose **Modify** in **Software & Updates** > **Other software** from *raring* to *quantal* distribution.

[image: other software]

Comment: Awesome. That seems to have worked. But then how do I install a version of a package older than the one currently installed?

Comment: @Jon I think it will work with `sudo apt-get remove --purge [package]` and again `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install [package]`

Comment: It still seems to install the newer version from the official repos, instead of the older version from the PPA.

Comment: If you want to install an old version, you should read this: [How to downgrade packages on Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/292314/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu)

Comment: For some reason, it's not recognizing anything from the quantal repo. Browsing by source in synaptic shows nothing from this PPA.

Comment: How to do this with CLI? I need to add an older PPA to a never Ubuntu while building a Docker image!

Answer (score 10):

After you add the repository, you can try to change the distribution manually:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/eudoxos-vim-breakindent-<version>.list 
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/eudoxos/vim-breakindent/ubuntu <version> main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/eudoxos/vim-breakindent/ubuntu <version> main
```

So just replace `<version>` on those entries with `quantal`, and do `sudo apt-get update`. It is not guaranteed it will work, but if it doesn't you can revert the canges or remove the PPA.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid manual change of the sources list you can use the following command to add the repository for a specific Ubuntu version:

`sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/eudoxos/vim-breakindent/ubuntu <needed_version_here> main"`

To remove the added repo:

`sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/eudoxos/vim-breakindent/ubuntu <needed_version_here> main"`