# Identifying PPA

Tags: update-manager, ppa

I have a ppa update error message:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/office/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have found several post on how to remove ppa's but they all require the ppa name. I know it might sound stupid, but I do not know what is the name of the faulty ppa.

Regards

Comment: The PPA name is usually after the `ppa.launchpad.net`.  So, the PPA is `upubuntu-com`.  Here is the actual PPA for that https://launchpad.net/~upubuntu-com/+ppa-packages

Comment: Probably need to remove the following file, then update:  `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/upubuntu-com-ppa-trusty.list`

Comment: To try and fix the issue: the ppa hasn't been updated since Quantal, so you could try using the quantal version following [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/293203/how-can-i-add-a-ppa-from-a-previous-release).

Answer (score 1):

The [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~upubuntu-com/+archive/ubuntu/office) has the name

```
ppa:upubuntu-com/office
```

There is a matching `list` file in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

Remove the file

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/upubuntu-com-ubuntu-office-trusty.list
```

and run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I have found the folder yet :
`frepie@Inspiron-1501:~$ sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/upubuntu-com-ubuntu-office-trusty.list
rm: cannot remove ‘/etc/apt/sources.list.d/upubuntu-com-ubuntu-office-trusty.list’: No such file or directory
frepie@Inspiron-1501:~$ `

Comment: Strange: when I use sudo, I get a ` No such file or directory` error message but when I do gksudo, it worked.