# Use Old PPA if New PPA is Not Available for New Ubuntu Version

Tags: ppa, repository, software-sources, sublime-text, 18.04

**1. What is best practice when a PPA has not been updated for a new release of Ubuntu?**

**2. Is it possible to use the PPA from the previous Ubuntu version? If so, how?**

Every time a new version of Ubuntu comes out I run into the issue that some of my PPA's have not been updated. For example, I just installed 18.04 which broke compatibility with Sublime Text 3 (which worked fine in 17.10). I am using Ansible to setup my repos on a clean install.

If I try to install Sublime using
    - ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu

I get an error that:

E:The repository http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file

(see also https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/sublime-text-3)

If I attempt to add the older 17.10 artful repo:

```
- ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu artful main
```

I get an error that:

W:Target Packages...is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list

Ansible code:

```
- name: install repositories
  become: true
  apt_repository: repo='{{ item }}'
  with_items:
    - deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse
    - deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
    - deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
    - deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    - deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse

    - ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu artful main
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a PPA from a previous release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293203/how-can-i-add-a-ppa-from-a-previous-release)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a PPA was not updated in time for a new Ubuntu release you have several options:

- wait until the PPA will be updated for the newer release
- install the package from source
- use another repository (see e.g. the [official repository for sublime text](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html#apt))

Only if you are brave enough and confident you can manage errors and dependency issues you can try the following:

- download and install a debian package for the previous release

Using a PPA designed for a previous release may lead to instabilities.