# Ubuntu 18.04 update problem 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, update-manager, 18.04

I can't update my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

This is error message:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiLkF.png)

How can I solve this? I try to change server main to US. But I got same error message.

Comment: Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8713/why-do-people-post-screenshots-of-their-terminals). Paste the text directly to your question and apply code formatting (the `{}` icon).

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028787/use-old-ppa-if-new-ppa-is-not-available-for-new-ubuntu-version, https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/xenial-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file