# How do i allow installing a program from an untrusted repository on Ubuntu Unity 22.10 Kinetic Kudu?

Tags: repository, unity-dash

I am testing to see if I can install the youtube scope for the dash in unity. here is the site i am reading: https://www.noobslab.com/2011/12/search-youtube-videos-in-ubuntu-unity.html .
when i try to install the repository for this program or scope in other words, i get this message in the terminal:
[image: terminal]

so my question is, how do i force installing this repository? How do i enable it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add a PPA from a previous release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293203/how-can-i-add-a-ppa-from-a-previous-release)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: no please help me understand i am not a tech person. i tried installing various scopes but it made unity crash and i had to install unity again!

Comment: i just want to know if there is still a way to get the youtube scope for 2022's version of unity

Comment: Probably not - you're linking to a PPA that hasn't had any updates in 9 years. I wouldn't expect much of that to work with a current version of Unity. But in your question you just want to force installing from this  old PPA and that's what the duplicate answers.

Comment: oh well im sad but ok thanks for telling me this :(