# Avoid Upgrade to Software Beta Versions

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, r, beta

Today my Update Manager in Ubuntu 12.04. updated R to the latest version called "R version 3.1.0 beta (2014-03-28 r65330) -- "Spring Dance""

I had a lot of trouble after the upgrade and I needed to manually downgrade the R-Core again as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292314/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu)

Is there a way to avoid upgrades to beta versions?

Comment: The version of R provided by Ubuntu 12.04 is still 2.14 (see http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=r-base ) - so you have added some repository which has provided a beta version.

Comment: Both the "official" CRAN Ubuntu repository and the ~marutter PPA now appear to have this version (the package is called `3.0.3.20140328` but identifies itself as `3.1.0 beta`), so you probably got it from one of those. Running `update.packages(checkBuilt=T)` should solve most problems with R packages not loading though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best one is not to use PPAs. I have no custom PPA so I have this candidate for installation:

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy r-base
r-base:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.0.1-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
     3.0.1-3ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
```

Once you have the PPA you should *purge* it

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:yourppa/ppa
```

This will revert the software automatically to the default version available in `universe`.

Comment: seems to be the case yes. Problem without adding the PPA is that you only get the approved versions which are sometimes a little bit outdated ... but okay.