# How do I rollback Recent Updates? 50+ crash reports upon login

Tags: 13.10, apt, kernel, updates

Am running 13.10 w/Cinnamon, but still have Unity installed. Everything was working fine until I responded to an update manager update notification. I tried rebooting into a prior kernel version, but that didn't fix this. I also tried changing session to Unity, but also same issues. The behavior after login is crash reports for 50+ applications, none of which are in startup applications.

Here's what got updated:

```
Start-Date: 2014-04-25  10:17:35
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.75'
Install: linux-image-extra-3.11.0-20-generic:amd64 (3.11.0-20.34), linux-image-3.11.0-20-generic:amd64 (3.11.0-20.34), linux-headers-3.11.0-20:amd64 (3.11.0-20.34), linux-headers-3.11.0-20-generic:amd64 (3.11.0-20.34)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (3.11.0.19.20, 3.11.0.20.21), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (34.0.1847.116-1, 34.0.1847.132-1), pepflashplugin-installer:amd64 (13.0.0.182~cr34.0.1847.116-1-0skunk0, 13.0.0.206~cr34.0.1847.132-1-0skunk0), chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:amd64 (33.0.1750.152-0ubuntu0.13.10.1~pkg984.1, 34.0.1847.116-0ubuntu~1.13.10.0~pkg991), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.11.0-19.33, 3.11.0-20.34), linux-image-generic:amd64 (3.11.0.19.20, 3.11.0.20.21), linux-generic:amd64 (3.11.0.19.20, 3.11.0.20.21)
End-Date: 2014-04-25  10:20:19
```

If I wanted to rollback to prior to this update, and have the earlier versions of the various, what is the best way to handle?

Comment: Have you considered the options here? http://askubuntu.com/questions/292314/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu

Comment: Good suggestion...The crash reports were making my system unusable, so I for now I disabled apport per this: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/09/ubuntu-13-10-quick-tip-disable-apport-error-reporting/ which has calmed things down. With apport disabled, how can I see what's crashed?

Comment: Isn't that what apport is for? I found this interesting info, maybe you can use it to identify crashes. http://sigquit.wordpress.com/2009/03/13/the-core-pattern/