# Installing GLIBC from source

Tags: 12.04, glibc

I want to install a different version of glibc on my Ubuntu 12.04. The questions are

1) Is it safe to have two versions of GLIBC on a system?

2) Should I remove the current installed GLIBC? **How?**

3) What is the procedure to install a new GLIBC?

Answer (score 1):

I am a new user, I can not comment, so I try to answer.

1. If you install a new version of GLIB: it means you are upgrading your old version. So you won't face any problem later.
2. If you want to install GLIB version 2.0 (you did not say which version you want to install), run this command: `sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev`
3. `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge <libglib_version_to_remove>`: it will remove GLIB and all its dependencies.

BUT: do not remove the older version if you want to use a new one because, as I said, if you install a new one then Ubuntu will upgrade your old version, simply.

Comment: In fact I want to install an older version of GLIBC. So I seek a manual installation procedure instead of apt-get

Comment: If you want an older version, I think this link will help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/292314/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu

Comment: glib is not glibc