# Ubuntu 14.04 Nvidia-331 Update Problem

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

After a recent update, Dec 11, I can no longer access the built-in LCD on Lenovo W520, with Quadro 1000M. Looking at /var/apt/history.log, I see the following updates:

```
Start-Date: 2014-12-11  21:32:08
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.171'
Install: linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic:amd64 (3.13.0-43.72), linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic:amd64 (3.13.0-43.72), linux-headers-
3.13.0-43-generic:amd64 (3.13.0-43.72), nvidia-331-updates-uvm:amd64 (331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4), linux-headers-3.13.0-43:amd64 (3.13.0-43
.72)
Upgrade: bind9-host:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-3, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.1), liblwres90:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-3, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.1), linux-header
s-generic:amd64 (3.13.0.40.47, 3.13.0.43.50), libdns100:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-3, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.1), libgail-3-0:amd64 (3.10.8-0ubunt
u1.2, 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.3), libisccfg90:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-3, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.1), libbind9-90:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-3, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubunt
u0.1), nvidia-opencl-icd-331-updates:amd64 (331.38-0ubuntu7.1, 331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4), dkms:amd64 (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5, 2.2.0.3-1.1ubun
tu5.14.04), nvidia-common:amd64 (0.2.91.5, 0.2.91.7), libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0:amd64 (2.4.4-1~ubuntu1, 2.4.7-1~ubuntu1), gir1.2-gtk
-3.0:amd64 (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.2, 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.3), libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:amd64 (2.4.4-1~ubuntu1, 2.4.7-1~ubuntu1), gir1.2-javascriptcore
gtk-3.0:amd64 (2.4.4-1~ubuntu1, 2.4.7-1~ubuntu1), nvidia-libopencl1-331-updates:amd64 (331.38-0ubuntu7.1, 331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4), ubun
tu-drivers-common:amd64 (0.2.91.5, 0.2.91.7), plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text:amd64 (0.8.8-0ubuntu17, 0.8.8-0ubuntu17.1), xserver-xorg-cor
e:amd64 (1.15.1-0ubuntu2.1, 1.15.1-0ubuntu2.5), libsepol1:amd64 (2.2-1, 2.2-1ubuntu0.1), flashplugin-installer:amd64 (11.2.202.424ubu
ntu0.14.04.1, 11.2.202.425ubuntu0.14.04.1), libgtk-3-bin:amd64 (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.2, 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.3), dnsutils:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-3, 
9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.1), plymouth:amd64 (0.8.8-0ubuntu17, 0.8.8-0ubuntu17.1), xserver-common:amd64 (1.15.1-0ubuntu2.1, 1.15.1-0ubuntu2
.5), libcuda1-331-updates:amd64 (331.38-0ubuntu7.1, 331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4), libwebkitgtk-3.0-0:amd64 (2.4.4-1~ubuntu1, 2.4.7-1~ubuntu1
), libgtk-3-0:amd64 (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.2, 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.3), libgtk-3-0:i386 (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.2, 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.3), libplymouth2:amd6
4 (0.8.8-0ubuntu17, 0.8.8-0ubuntu17.1), lightdm:amd64 (1.10.1-0ubuntu1, 1.10.3-0ubuntu2), libgtk-3-common:amd64 (3.10.8-0ubuntu1.2, 3
.10.8-0ubuntu1.3), libwebkitgtk-3.0-common:amd64 (2.4.4-1~ubuntu1, 2.4.7-1~ubuntu1), liblightdm-gobject-1-0:amd64 (1.10.1-0ubuntu1, 1
.10.3-0ubuntu2), libwebkitgtk-1.0-common:amd64 (2.4.4-1~ubuntu1, 2.4.7-1~ubuntu1), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.13.0-40.69, 3.13.0-43.72),
 libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0:amd64 (2.4.4-1~ubuntu1, 2.4.7-1~ubuntu1), plymouth-label:amd64 (0.8.8-0ubuntu17, 0.8.8-0ubuntu17.1), plym
outh-theme-ubuntu-logo:amd64 (0.8.8-0ubuntu17, 0.8.8-0ubuntu17.1), gir1.2-webkit-3.0:amd64 (2.4.4-1~ubuntu1, 2.4.7-1~ubuntu1), linux-
image-generic:amd64 (3.13.0.40.47, 3.13.0.43.50), libisccc90:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-3, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.1), libisc95:amd64 (9.9.5.dfsg-
3, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.1), nvidia-331-updates:amd64 (331.38-0ubuntu7.1, 331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4)
End-Date: 2014-12-11  21:42:20
```

Here is the output of dkms:

```
~$ dkms status
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-331-updates, 331.113, 3.13.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-331-updates, 331.113, 3.13.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-331-updates-uvm, 331.113, 3.13.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-331-updates-uvm, 331.113, 3.13.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 4.3.10, 3.13.0-27-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 4.3.10, 3.13.0-29-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 4.3.10, 3.13.0-30-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 4.3.10, 3.13.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 4.3.10, 3.13.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 4.3.10, 3.13.0-34-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 4.3.10, 3.13.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 4.3.10, 3.13.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 4.3.10, 3.13.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 4.3.10, 3.13.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 4.3.10, 3.13.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 4.3.10, 3.13.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
```

I also see the following in kernel logs:

```
Dec 15 22:19:50 Ubuntu kernel: [    4.391366] [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.1.2 20120801 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
Dec 15 22:19:50 Ubuntu kernel: [    4.395356] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
Dec 15 22:19:50 Ubuntu kernel: [    4.395359] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
Dec 15 22:19:50 Ubuntu kernel: [    4.399387] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
Dec 15 22:19:50 Ubuntu kernel: [    4.403024] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine was not called for 1 device(s).
Dec 15 22:19:50 Ubuntu kernel: [    4.403027] NVRM: This can occur when a driver such as: 
Dec 15 22:19:50 Ubuntu kernel: [    4.403027] NVRM: nouveau, rivafb, nvidiafb or rivatv 
Dec 15 22:19:50 Ubuntu kernel: [    4.403027] NVRM: was loaded and obtained ownership of the NVIDIA device(s).
Dec 15 22:19:50 Ubuntu kernel: [    4.403029] NVRM: Try unloading the conflicting kernel module (and/or
Dec 15 22:19:50 Ubuntu kernel: [    4.403029] NVRM: reconfigure your kernel without the conflicting
Dec 15 22:19:50 Ubuntu kernel: [    4.403029] NVRM: driver(s)), then try loading the NVIDIA kernel module
Dec 15 22:19:50 Ubuntu kernel: [    4.403029] NVRM: again.
```

Tried reinstalling nvidia-331 with no effect. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a bug described at 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/nvidia/+bug/1401434

A workaround may be to downgrade the nvidia driver 331.113 to 331.38. This helped me: 
[How to downgrade packages on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292314/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Indeed that was the case, thank you for sharing your results.

Comment: Another option might be to switch to the 'open' Nouveau driver by removing the `nvidia-331` package and installing the `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` package. I've had issues with the 'closed' NVidia driver quite a few times, but never had them with the Nouveau driver...