# Google chrome doesn't open in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: google-chrome

I try to open Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04 but it doesn't open.
I tried to reinstall it twice but no luck.
Has anyone the same issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE: Apparently, "switching my computer off and switching it back on again" worked for me. However, I don't like errors which randomly disappear; they have a nasty habit of randomly reappearing.]

I'm seeing this too. This is Google Chrome 39.0.2171.99-1 on Ubuntu 14.04. Attempting to run in terminal produces

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable: line 83: /chrome: No such file or directory
```

and I have to terminate manually with `Ctrl+C`. As far as I can tell, there's no previous version available in the repository for a downgrade (followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292314/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu)).

(Would post this as a comment except that, for some reason, SE insists that you have to have reputation to comment, which seems... counter-productive.)