# How to downgrade the gnome terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, downgrade

I want to downgrade the gnome-terminal from 3.10.2 to 3.6.2, like in [How to downgrade packages on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292314/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu) I tried using synaptic but without success and I don't think it's as easy as with any other application.

Comment: Whats the output of `apt-cache policy gnome-terminal`?

Comment: gnome-terminal:
  Instalados: 3.10.2-0ubuntu1~trusty1
  Candidato:  3.10.2-0ubuntu1~trusty1
  Tabla de versión:
 *** 3.10.2-0ubuntu1~trusty1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.6.2-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ubuntu.unc.edu.ar/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal=3.6.2-0ubuntu1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the output of `apt-cache policy gnome-terminal` you have installed `gnome-terminal 3.10` via PPA and `gnome-terminal 3.6` is still available at the main repository. So do downgrade from 3.10 to 3.6 run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal=3.6.2-0ubuntu1
```

Here is another method that involves removing the PPA:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

Comment: I run your code but doesn't work

Comment: @DiegoSilvera: Please check my edits..

Comment: Thank you, now works. What do you do with the extra lines?

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is:

1. Save / Finish Up Whatever you're doing in the GUI (LightDM/Unity).
2. Go to a TTY Session (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>).
3. Login with your username and password.
4. Stop LightDM.
5. Downgrade Gnome Terminal
6. Start LightDM.

I'll start from step 4.

### Step 4: Stop LightDM

To stop lightdm, enter the following command:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

### Step 5: Downgrade Gnome Terminal

Command(s):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal=3.6.2
```

### Step 6: Start LightDM

Command:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

You should then be directed to the GUI login screen. Volla!

See this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else arrives here and is unable to target version 3.6.2 via apt-get the following script found [here](https://gist.github.com/buithehoa/4903c09d8941107823bf) worked for me:

```
wget http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-data_3.6.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal_3.6.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i gnome-terminal_3.6.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb gnome-terminal-data_3.6.2-0ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo apt-mark hold gnome-terminal
sudo apt-mark hold gnome-terminal-data
```

I was on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 going from gnome-terminal version 3.18 to 3.6.2 and worked without a hitch.