# How to downgrade smbclient

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm trying to downgrade smbclient as is no longer working with backuppc. I have followed the instructions in this post [How to downgrade packages on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292314/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu) but it doesn't seem to work.

I ran

```
sudo apt-cache showpkg smbclient
sudo apt-get install smbclient=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2
```

But this does nothing. smbclient version is still Version 4.3.9-Ubuntu.

I have tried purging smbclient and then re-installing. This results in unmet dependencies.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo apt-get install smbclient=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
smbclient : Depends: samba-common (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2) but    2:4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
            Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2) but  2:4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo apt-get install smbclient=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2 samba-common=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2 samba-libs=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
smbclient : Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2) but  2:4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: Try removing `samba-common`  and `samba-libs`, then retry installing `smbclient=2:4.1.6`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo aptitude install smbclient=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2
```

Typical! After hours of searching for an answer I find it 2 minutes after posting the question. Aptitude takes care of the dependencies. I didn't realise that apt-get wouldn't do that.