# How to place desktop icon titles in the center?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, icons, fonts, 32-bit

After a recent update (2 days ago) the names of icons on the Desktop are not aligned correctly. I am using Arc theme with Paper icon set but this problem persists even with default theme and icon set.

[image]

The icons themselves are aligned perfectly, only the names are not.

[image] [image]

```
locale | grep -i collate
```

gives: `LC_COLLATE="el_GR.UTF-8"`

Comment: Please run `locale | grep -i collate` and show us the output by editing the questions.

Comment: Ok, great. I read the question badly, thinking that sorting was an issue. Now I understands it's not. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: No problem, your request made me think that this may be a result of a problem in the display language because there was an update of Greek language and locale among other updates two days ago. I changed the display language to US English but the problem persists so I don't think that this is a display language oriented problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be [bug 1598316](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk2-engines-murrine/+bug/1598316).

I downgraded gtk2-engines-murrine from 0.98.2-0ubuntu2.1 to 0.98.2-0ubuntu2 which fixed the issue for me.

[How to downgrade package](https://askubuntu.com/a/292315/568978)

Comment: This worked for me! I ran `sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine=0.98.2-0ubuntu2`

Comment: The downgrade resolved the issue!Thank you very much!