# Desktop icon foreground text is way offset

Tags: gui, gtk, settings, gtk-2

I'm not sure where I need to go to tweak this icon text being so far offset. Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

I'm using Xubuntu 16.04 64-bit with Arc theme and Paper icon theme.

EDIT: This happens when the update shown below is applied. Here's a [link to patch causing the problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk2-engines-murrine/+bug/1294699).

[image]

Comment: same problems as [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/798484/how-to-place-desktop-icon-titles-in-the-center) (but no answer to this one yet...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the bug related to the issue:
[gtk2-engines-murrine desktop text shadow problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk2-engines-murrine/+bug/1598316)

Until that's fixed, I downgraded to the previous version of the package

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine=0.98.2-0ubuntu2
```

Then to prevent the package manager from automatically updating the package in the future

```
sudo echo "gtk2-engines-murrine hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Comment: There seems to be a patch out now (0.98.2-0ubuntu2.2) that fixes this. I haven't tried it yet. I did the above "hold" fix on the package and that worked fine. How can I now remove the hold and install the newest version?