# How can I downgrade from Audacity 2.2.0 to 2.1.3?

Tags: downgrade, audacity

I'm using Lubuntu 17.04. I'd like to downgrade Audacity from 2.2.0 (too buggy) to 2.1.3 but am unsure how to do that.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: What procedure did you use to install Audacity 2.2.0?

Comment: First you should file a bug report against Audacity. Then see https://askubuntu.com/questions/292314/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu . NOTE: IMHO Ubuntu is not the best distro to do this with, Ubuntu is sort of designed to always run the latest packages in the repositories. Arch or gentoo offer finer control.

Comment: 2.2.0 was installed during an automatic system update.

Comment: @Sage. The current version of Audacity in the Ubuntu archives is 2.1.2 - you must have used a PPA from somewhere to use a newer version.  Perhaps [https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/audacity?field.series_filter=zesty](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/audacity?field.series_filter=zesty)  If this was the case then you could `sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/audacity` to revert to the version in the Ubuntu archives.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks so much for your help. I was able to find the DEB file under "view package details" on this page: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/audacity and install, then lock the version via Synaptic as detailed in the link you gave me.

Comment: Had you been connected to the PPA to obtain the automatic upgrade, and have you removed that PPA from your system?

Comment: You're EXACTLY right, thanks so much. I removed the PPA and the problem disappeared.