# How to downgrade glibc version on Ubuntu 20.04 6

Tags: downgrade

Right now, we have upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 6 version having `glibc` version as 2.31.
However, there are some packages which requires native packages. For example, icu is dependent upon icu-native which is compiled with GLIBCXX_3.4.30, but when icu is getting compiled in it is checking for 3.4.30 but libstdc++ library only supports till 3.4.28.

So, I have following questions:

- How can we fix this? Is it possible to downgrade the `glibc` version on Ubuntu.

Sumit

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This sounds like an inherently bad idea. `glibc` is an integral part of the system, and messing with the version (especially downgrading) would be dangerous. Also, there's something about your versions that I don't understand. How does `glibc` 2.31 relate to libstdc++ 3.4.30?

Comment: In general, if you require special software with special dependencies, such software is best run in containerized or virtual environments, where the environment can be customized without affecting the host system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to downgrade packages on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292314/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu)

Comment: @karel I would caution against trying to downgrade glibc unless one _really_ knows what they're doing and has a _really_ good reason for doing so that isn't [an XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @cocomac The problem with this question is that it's not possible to safely downgrade the glibc version on Ubuntu, so the best answer to this question is that there is no answer. Since there is no answer to it, I'm using the duplicate question to close this unanswerable question.